# NXT 2.0: Combine Line follow and Obstacle avoidance?

Tags: nxt

I have seen code sample that do line follow and code samples that do obstacle avoidance. But are there any code samples that combine both line follow and obstacle avoidance?

Answer (score 0):

One of the bits of code which I built for an assignment does this. It follows the rules of Australian Robocup Rescue.

So if you look at navigateBottle() and followLine() at this link [Click here for the code](http://pastebin.com/nNKMzKHZ). That should help you in understanding in how you can do this.

This does use 2 Light Sensors and a Sonar Sensor. It does a bouncing effect between the 2 sensors and Sonar for seeing if objects are in front of it.

Sam